# Removing specific red/yellow underlines(error underline) in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, error-handling, compiler-errors

I saw some similar answers from Stack Overflow. Yet, most of them are just simply removing all the error underlines. What if I just want to remove the error code in a specific line? I saw some users have asked this previously but no solution yet, so I want to raise it again.

Million thanks for your help!

[for example: some lines like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfhH2.png)

Answer (score 1):

Set some underline colors you want to transparent:

`Settings > Workbench > ColorCustomizations`

Add these properties:

```
        "editorError.foreground":   "#00000000",
        "editorWarning.foreground": "#00000000",
        "editorInfo.foreground":    "#00000000"
```